Searching with Populated Fields in MongoDB: Is It Possible?
I have 2 tables like claims and orders, in claim table i have order id. When i query this it gets results of ordel table too with selected values. But i want when i send search parameter it only search values from main table that is claim but not compare search value with populate table.
Controller
Query parameter is search
Fields to search:
client_id: Type Number in Parent table (Working)
store_order_number: Type String in orders table (Not Working)
if (search) {
      const searchRegex = new RegExp(search, "i"); // case-insensitive search

      query.$or = [
        { "order_id.store_order_number": { $regex: searchRegex } },
        { "order_id.protect_order_number": { $regex: searchRegex } },
        {
          $expr: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: { $toString: "$claim_id" },
              regex: searchRegex,
            },
          },
        },
      ];
    }

Service Function
let claims = await schemaClaims
      .find(query, projection)
      .populate([
        {
          path: "order_id",
          model: "Order",
          select: "_id store_order_number protect_order_number",
          options: { lean: true },
        },
      ])
      .sort(sortQuery)
      .skip(parseInt(skip))
      .limit(limit);

What i have understand that search parameter work only on main table not the populated one. And i just want if it is possible with any way we can use search for child tables which we have populated.

Direct, no, you cannot filter populated fields using a filter passed to the database.
The populate method is run on the client side after the initial results have been returned from the database, so it is too late for the passed filter to apply.
You could rewrite your find query as an aggregation, filter the parent table using $match, then use a $lookup stage to retrieve values from the child table, and another $match to filter based on the fields from the child table.
